# User manually create model fields for post [django]

Tags: python, django

So I want to create a post by letting the user add a section/subtitle as they need it, but I have no idea how to go about creating this, I currently just have a  title, preview and content block in a form but want the user to be able to create as many subtitle and content blocks as they want. Any help is very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Well that's really basic database design question... What you describe is a "one to many" relationship (one "post" has many "subtitle-plus-content"), which is implemented using a table for the "subtitle-plus-content" records, with a foreign key on the "post" table (so we know which "subtitle-plus-content" records belong to which "post" record).

In Django, this is simply done by creatin a matching model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_lenght=xxx)
    content = models.TextField()
    # etc


class ContentBlock(models.Model):
    """ A block with additionnal subtitle and content for posts """ 
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_lenght=xxx)
    content = models.TextField()
    # etc
```

You'll find [more documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#many-to-one-relationships)

Comment: sorry I didn't explain my issue well enough, I meant how can I add an additional field via a user click 
So the end result I want is to have a create page with buttons saying add paragraph ,add image, add subtitle etc

Comment: The question was clear and the answer is the same (in its principle). This is basic relational database modeling really, and a very standard cms feature.